# Somar valores de uma string atribuindo valores as letras (Python)

Tags: python, string, dicionário

**Objetivo:**

Atribuir valores a uma string baseada em um dicionario com chaves e valores

**Exemplo:**

Tenho uma string neste formato:

`str = 'ABCD'`

e um dicionário neste.

`dic = {'A' : 71, 'B' : 103, 'C' : 115, 'D' : 129}`

**Script**

```
for i in aa:
    soma += dic.get(i, 0)
print(round(soma, 3))
```

**Problema a resolver:**

Necessito criar um laço for para atribuir valores a 'str' e somar. Tipo 71 + 103 + 115 + 129 e dar o valor final da soma (418) e se eu atribuir n valores no dicionário o programa seja capaz de me dar a soma final.

Obrigado a todos que puderem ajudar....

Leo

Comment: Olá LCalado, Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Na sua pergunta você está apenas compartilhando o enunciado de um exercício. O que você já tentou? A ideia do site não é fazer o seu trabalho da faculdade ou lição de casa para você, mas se você estiver com dificuldade em alguma parte específica, compartilhe o seu código, diga o que já tentou fazer e qual está sendo a dificuldade, assim você aumenta as suas chances em conseguir uma boa resposta.

Comment: Obrigado Anthony, farei da próxima vez!!!Neste caso fiquei tentando sair do lugar e não consegui, talvez pela grande inexperiência, tanto aqui no stack quanto com a linguagem.

Comment: `print(sum(dic[i] for i in str))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para o caso específico, isso resolve

```
str = 'ABCD'
dic = {'A' : 71, 'B' : 103, 'C' : 115, 'D' : 129}

soma = 0
for l in str:
    soma += dic.get(l, 0)
    
    
print(soma)
```

O resultado acima é 418

O fato de utilizar o `dic.get()` é para o caso da letra ou outra coisa não estar no dicionário e, neste caso, o valor atribuído é 0 (zero)

Exemplo:

```
str = 'MNOPQ'
```

Como nenhuma das letras está naquele `dic`, o resultado da soma será 0 (zero)

Comment: Obrigado Paulo, já apliquei aqui!!!! Muito agradecido pela explicação!!!